# android studio tabbed activity button to new activity

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new to android, but I am going to create an android app that will use webview. I know I can search some basic info everywhere, but somehow I don't know the key word of what I want in android.

I am using tabbed activity, as shown:
[tabbed activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IgDhQ.png)

I have already added a button, which will be used to go to a new activity, which is a webview. But I don't know if it is really an activity. The required page or activity is shown: [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KhXU0.jpg)

I know it is a webview, but I don't know if I should create a new activity to hold this web.

Thanks.

Button:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_puzzle, container, false);
    btnTower = (ImageButton) v.findViewById(R.id.imageButton3);

    btnTower.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), WebActivity.class);
            getActivity().startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return v;
}
```

manifest:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".WebActivity"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar">

    </activity>
```

Comment: you should load webview in same page

Comment: No need to create new activity? If so, how to hide those layout of tabbed activity?

Comment: you created fragment right? for both tab

Comment: yes, but by default, tab one is main activity

Comment: you have two fragments inside one activity.? second fragment contains that button. so on click of that button replace that layout with webview

Comment: No need to create a new activity to hold the webview?

Comment: yes. no need of activity

Comment: I have two fragments now, can you show me some details? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

From documentation :

Adding a webview in your XML:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webview"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
```

And load in URL inside the webview:

```
    WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
myWebView.loadUrl("http://www.example.com");
```

Also don't forget to set the permission in the manifest:

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    ...
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new activity, in that activity's layout you can add a webView having MATCH_PARENT attributes for its width and height.

Then use intent to go to that activity and perform your desired operations on the webview.

Answer (score 0):

First You need to implement `onclick` listener in your fragment.

```
  button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
             @Override
             public void onClick(View v) {
               final Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(),WebViewActivity.class);
        getActivity().startActivity(intent); 
   }
          });
```

In `WebViewActivity` class

follow below link : https://www.mkyong.com/android/android-webview-example/

This WebViewActivity you have to define in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Comment: But will the "close-window" button appear in the left hand corner?

Comment: @newbie Not understand can you please give me more details

Comment: Just as the picture shown in the "page" link above. There is a "cross sign" (close window) button to go back to the tabbed activity.

Comment: I think it is not. Android studio doesn't provide this button when using webview?

Comment: So just implement the onclick listener for that "X" and wright the code finish() in that OnclickListener

Comment: sorry, but it doesn't response when i click on the button, as I am in the fragment

Comment: hi sir, it would be appreciated if you could help